# Prometheus Alert Rules with docker label only working with prefix "container_label_"?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, cadvisor

I am running a prometheus-cadvisor.. monitoring dockerized system. In the docker containers that are to be monitored, I have

```
docker-compose.yml
    ...
      labels: somelabel: "somename"
```

in a Prometheus

```
alert.rules_containers

        ALERT missing_container
          IF 
        count(rate(container_last_seen{name=~".+",somelabel=~"somename"}[5m])) by (somelabel,host) < 10
          FOR 5m
          ANNOTATIONS {...}
```

but this does not work

it only works if I change

`somelabel` to `container_label_somelabel`

Why ist that. I could not find any explanation anywhere. And all the example code I found was using labels the same way I did in the non-working version.

Answer (score 0):

it seems this was a recent change in cAdvisor

https://github.com/google/cadvisor/pull/1426